# Promise not getting resolved when using Page Object Model with Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm trying to implement the Page Object Model in my project, and I'm having trouble getting it to work. I want to the title of the current page using browser.getTitle(), which works perfectly when used directly in **login.spec.js**, but doesn't work when moved to **login.po.js**. Here's what my setup currently looks like:

### login.spec.js

```
var LoginPage = require('../../pages/user/login.po.js'),
    expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('Login', function() {
    var page;

    beforeEach(function () {
        page = new LoginPage();
    });

    it('should be able to get the page title', function() {
        expect(page.getLoginPageTitle).to.equal('Test');
    });
});
```

### login.po.js

```
'use strict';

var LoginPage = function(){
    browser.get('http://localhost:3000/');
};

LoginPage.prototype = Object.create({}, {
    getLoginPageTitle: {get: function() {
        browser.getTitle().then(function(res){
            return res;
        });
    }}
});

module.exports = LoginPage;
```

And the error I get:
    `AssertionError: expected undefined to equal 'Test'`

Upon further investigating, it seems like the browser.getTitle() promise in my login.po.js isn't getting resolved.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? The page loads correctly in Chrome and Chrome shows the correct page title.

Comment: are you using any framework and if so which is it?

Comment: I'm using mocha with chai

Comment: promises have a guaranteed future they must either resolve of reject so i think you should add the rejected check and try to see the error you get back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it eventually! (no pun intended)

I simply had to use [chai-as-promised](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised) as well as use [wswebcreation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912708/promise-not-getting-resolved-when-using-page-object-model-with-protractor/44912953#44912953)'s answer. Here's my setup now:

### login.spec.js

```
var LoginPage = require('../../pages/user/login.po.js'),
    chai = require('chai'),
    expect = require('chai').expect,
    chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');

chai.use(chaiAsPromised)

describe('Login', function() {
    var page;

    beforeEach(function () {
        page = new LoginPage();
    });

    it('should be able to get the page title', function() {
        expect(page.getLoginPageTitle).to.eventually.equal('Test');
    });
});
```

### login.po.js

```
'use strict';

var LoginPage = function(){
    browser.get('http://localhost:3000/');
};

LoginPage.prototype = Object.create({}, {
    getLoginPageTitle: {get: function() {
        return browser.getTitle();
    }}
});

module.exports = LoginPage;
```

Answer (score 1):

you should add an extra return in your PageObject. You are returning the result of the resolved promise `browser.getTitle()`, but not the promise itself, see below.

```js
'use strict';

var LoginPage = function() {
  browser.get('http://localhost:3000/');
};

LoginPage.prototype = Object.create({}, {
  getLoginPageTitle: {
    get: function() {
      return browser.getTitle();
    }
  }
});

module.exports = LoginPage;
```